# Re-compiling PulseAudio

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio

I'm having an issue getting PulseAudio re-compiled. I decided to recompile to try out the WebRTC echo cancellation as well as get access to the equalizer.

I'm not doing anything crazy here, I simply did the following:

```
apt-get source pulseaudio
sudo apt-get build-dep pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install libwebrtc-audio-processing-dev
cd pulsaudio-4.0
#Add --enable-webrtc-aec to debian/rules
dpkg-builpackage -uc -us -b -j8
```

I am greeted by the following error while compiling:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/soundcard.h:1:0,
             from utils/padsp.c:35:
utils/padsp.c: In function 'dsp_ioctl':
utils/padsp.c:2280:14: error: 'SOUND_PCM_READ_RATE_is_obsolete' undeclared (first use in this function)
     case SOUND_PCM_READ_RATE:
          ^
utils/padsp.c:2280:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
utils/padsp.c:2288:14: error: 'SOUND_PCM_READ_CHANNELS_is_obsolete' undeclared (first use in this function)
     case SOUND_PCM_READ_CHANNELS:
          ^
utils/padsp.c:2296:14: error: 'SOUND_PCM_READ_BITS_is_obsolete' undeclared (first use in this function)
     case SOUND_PCM_READ_BITS:
          ^
make[4]: *** [libpulsedsp_la-padsp.lo] Error 1
```

Even removing --enable-webrtc-aec from the build options, it will not compile properly. Does anybody know what's going wrong here?

Clarification: There is a way to avoid this build issue by using --disable-oss-wrapper, however this option is enabled (by default) in the source package itself. If this was the source used to build the package, how did it get built in the first place? What I'm my trying to figure out is how to set up my system to build the default package (with additional functionality) and without removing aspects that *should* be available as per the version available in the repos. This should be a trivial process but for some reason it's not.

EDIT: So, I thought that perhaps a 5.0 build might help me avoid the issue, but I get the same error with PulseAudio 5.0 as I do with 4.0. The header its complaining about is provided by libc6-dev. Is it possible something changed in libc6 to bring this on?

Comment: I could not recreate this error myself but I did find a few posted bug report for your exact errors and according to the devs this is fixed, 14.04 only ships with version 4 of pulse audio so maybe the update is not included here ? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756914 You can try this latest version 6 from pulse prehaps http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/

Comment: When you say you could not reproduce it, do you mean you actually got it compiled? If so, was that in 14.04?

Comment: Yes, it seems to compile fine, using your commands from the question, there was a long series of errors but it still compiled and packaged it as a .deb, also this is on 14.04.2 (or whatever the latest . release is)

Comment: Do you used a PCI sound card ? What are the contents of /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/soundcard.h ? Some thing (3 things it seems) are wrong in this file, mine has only one line "#include <linux/soundcard.h>" and the file it references is a long driver file and it contains the errors you mentioned. I would back this file up (copy to your /home or something and edit the lines that gave you the errors to match the next comment as im out of letters.

Comment: #define SOUND_PCM_READ_RATE  _SIOR ('P', 2, int) - 
#define SOUND_PCM_READ_CHANNELS  _SIOR ('P', 6, int) - 
#define SOUND_PCM_READ_BITS  _SIOR ('P', 5, int) - 
#define SOUND_PCM_READ_FILTER  _SIOR ('P', 7, int) - Be careful to check the formating as the comment box squashed it all together

Comment: Hm, I'll try that out. It's possible that the reason is that I'm using 14.04.0. Since I did a fresh install with 14.04.0, it seems I'm missing some packages that come on the 14.04.2 image such as an updated kernel (which I got on my own).

Comment: Kernel seems like a promising lead, perhaps choose 3.13.0-48-generic
in grub, that is the one I used while compiling

Answer (score 1):

It appears that since upgrading to the Utopic or Vivid LTS enablement stack, this issue has been solved. I decided to try it again recently and had no issues compiling except issues with parallel jobs. I had to remove `oss4-dev`, but this was a holdover from the last time I tried since `apt-file` told me that oss4-dev would provide a version of the file it was complaining about.

All told, WebRTC echo cancellation is outrageously good. I tested it blaring music through my speakers and it cancelled out everything. The end result was a little muddy, but that minor side effect it well worth the benefits. My thought: WebRTC echo cancellation should really be in mainline.